# Unable to access or mount iPod touch [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: mount, ipod

On attaching the iPod touch Ubuntu throws a message "Unable to mount [name]'s iPod touch" with a sub message: "Unable to connect." I have been unable to pinpoint any specific troubleshooting or workarounds for this. (If it helps - the device has recently been reset/erased and then re-setup, it worked before the reset)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, though my ipod touch has NOT been recently reset (that I know, I bought it second hand).

Have you installed libimobiledevice from the ubuntu software centre? That has allowed ubuntu 14.04 to see my ipod touch device (it appears as an icon in the left hand side vertical menu and in the file manager), but NOT to see the files yet. More work to do.

It is surprising that there is no feedback at all for libimobiledevice in the ubuntu software centre...